# Json Scraping, output_dict

Tags: python, discord

```
# GET NEWS To JSON FILE
def get_news():
    r = requests.get("https://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.json")
    json_file = r.json()
    # Filter python objects with list comprehensions
    output_dict = [x for x in json_file if (x['impact'] == 'High' or x['impact'] == 'Holiday')]
    # Transform python object back into json
    output_json = json.dumps(output_dict, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    # Show json
    # print(output_json)
    return output_json
```

the json file has impact: High , impact: Medium , impact: Low , impact: Holiday..
4 ways an entry could be in the json file

Now in the code i have only have high and holiday, how can i add low and medium to it while it staying to work

Comment: What do you mean by "adding" low and medium? Are you referring to the condition in the list comprehension?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value

Comment: `output_dict = [x for x in json_file if (x['impact'] == 'High' or x['impact'] == 'Holiday' or x['impact'] == 'Medium' or x['impact'] == 'Low')]`

Comment: That's a bad solution @alexpdev -- maybe check out the two posts I linked for something that can actually scale, cuts down on excessive operations, is clearer, and faster?

Comment: @ddejohn  Its the solution that requires the least amount of understanding and the least amount of changes to the code.   It's obvious that the OP isn't very familiar with python and I didn't think this question warranted a full answer

Comment: Interesting strategy, teaching OP bad habits, sending them down a path with a dead end instead of helping them grow as a developer...

Comment: You're right that this question doesn't warrant an answer though -- because it already has the canonical answer documented in dozens of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this.

```
impacts = ['High', 'Low', 'Medium', 'Holiday']
outPut_dicts = [x for x in json_data if (x.get('impact') in impacts)]
```

Comment: File "main.py", line 77, in called_once_a_day
    await message_channel.send(embed=embed)
  File "/home/runner/Infinity-Forex-News/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "/home/runner/Infinity-Forex-News/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed: Embed size exceeds maximum size of 6000